# Creating a ranking form in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I am new to Laravel and I am trying to create a from where a user and rank items and it will go store in the database but I cannot find a single resource to assist me. I would like to have a ranking system between 3 appliances, say fridge, microwave and stove. The user can rank the appliances in order of preference. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Be more specific in your question please. What do you exactly want?

Comment: I have a form and I would like to have a ranking system between 3 appliances, say fridge, microwave and stove. The user can rank the appliances in order of preference. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Ah that's better for understanding what you want. Please update your question with this information, so people instantly understand the question :)

Answer (score 0):

you should add to order column from your database.

for example your database columns:

1. name
2. description
3. order

Then try this:

```
Model::latest('order')->get()
```

or:

```
Model::orderBy('order', 'desc')->get()
```

the user will need to update the order.